# A messagebox keeping popping up in my centos VNC server asking to change proxy settings?

Tags: centos, authentication, vnc

I have included a screenshot of what it looks like. It keeps appearing and in the morning you to close it 50 times.

Could you please help me identify where the problem lies?

**NOTE:** It's CentOs 6 with tigervnc.

[image: The prompt]

#### EDIT

Here is the `ps -eaf` is at the bottom.

This is the detail pane:

[image: Details]

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/init
root         2     0  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
root         3     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [migration/0]
root         4     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [migration/0]
root         6     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/0]
root         7     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [migration/1]
root         8     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [migration/1]
root         9     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/1]
root        10     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/1]
root        11     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [migration/2]
root        12     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [migration/2]
root        13     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/2]
root        14     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/2]
root        15     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [migration/3]
root        16     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [migration/3]
root        17     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/3]
root        18     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/3]
root        19     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [migration/4]
root        20     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [migration/4]
root        21     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/4]
root        22     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/4]
root        23     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [migration/5]
root        24     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [migration/5]
root        25     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/5]
root        26     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/5]
root        27     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [migration/6]
root        28     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [migration/6]
root        29     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/6]
root        30     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/6]
root        31     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [migration/7]
root        32     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [migration/7]
root        33     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/7]
root        34     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/7]
root        35     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [events/0]
root        36     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [events/1]
root        37     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [events/2]
root        38     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [events/3]
root        39     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [events/4]
root        40     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [events/5]
root        41     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [events/6]
root        42     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [events/7]
root        43     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [cpuset]
root        44     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [khelper]
root        45     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [netns]
root        46     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [async/mgr]
root        47     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [pm]
root        48     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [xenwatch]
root        49     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [xenbus]
root        50     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [sync_supers]
root        51     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [bdi-default]
root        52     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kintegrityd/0]
root        53     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kintegrityd/1]
root        54     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kintegrityd/2]
root        55     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kintegrityd/3]
root        56     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kintegrityd/4]
root        57     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kintegrityd/5]
root        58     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kintegrityd/6]
root        59     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kintegrityd/7]
root        60     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kblockd/0]
root        61     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kblockd/1]
root        62     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kblockd/2]
root        63     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kblockd/3]
root        64     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kblockd/4]
root        65     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kblockd/5]
root        66     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kblockd/6]
root        67     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kblockd/7]
root        68     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [ata/0]
root        69     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [ata/1]
root        70     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [ata/2]
root        71     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [ata/3]
root        72     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [ata/4]
root        73     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [ata/5]
root        74     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [ata/6]
root        75     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [ata/7]
root        76     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [ata_aux]
root        77     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [ksuspend_usbd]
root        78     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [khubd]
root        79     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kseriod]
root        80     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [md/0]
root        81     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [md/1]
root        82     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [md/2]
root        83     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [md/3]
root        84     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [md/4]
root        85     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [md/5]
root        86     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [md/6]
root        87     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [md/7]
root        88     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [md_misc/0]
root        89     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [md_misc/1]
root        90     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [md_misc/2]
root        91     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [md_misc/3]
root        92     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [md_misc/4]
root        93     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [md_misc/5]
root        94     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [md_misc/6]
root        95     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [md_misc/7]
root        96     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [khungtaskd]
root        97     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kswapd0]
root        98     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [ksmd]
root        99     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [aio/0]
root       100     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [aio/1]
root       101     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [aio/2]
root       102     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [aio/3]
root       103     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [aio/4]
root       104     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [aio/5]
root       105     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [aio/6]
root       106     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [aio/7]
root       107     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [crypto/0]
root       108     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [crypto/1]
root       109     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [crypto/2]
root       110     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [crypto/3]
root       111     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [crypto/4]
root       112     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [crypto/5]
root       113     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [crypto/6]
root       114     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [crypto/7]
root       119     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kthrotld/0]
root       120     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kthrotld/1]
root       121     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kthrotld/2]
root       122     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kthrotld/3]
root       123     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kthrotld/4]
root       124     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kthrotld/5]
root       125     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kthrotld/6]
root       126     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kthrotld/7]
root       128     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [khvcd]
root       129     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kpsmoused]
root       130     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [usbhid_resumer]
root       191     1  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 /bin/plymouthd --attach-to-sessi
root       267     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kjournald]
root       339     1  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/udevd -d
root       648   339  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/udevd -d
root       651     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kstriped]
root       694     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [flush-202:1]
root       716     2  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 [kauditd]
root       717     1  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /etc/rc.d/rc 3
root       863     1  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 auditd
root       888     1  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/rsyslogd -i /var/run/syslo
root       902     1  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 mdadm --monitor --scan -f --pid-
dbus       911     1  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon --system
root       921     1  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager --pid-file=/var/r
root       925     1  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/modem-manager
root       934     1  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 cupsd -C /etc/cups/cupsd.conf
68         992     1  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 hald
root       993   992  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 hald-runner
root       995     1  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant -c /etc
root      1040   993  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 hald-addon-input: Listening on /
root      1058     1  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
root      1069     1  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd/vsf
root      1080     1  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 guacd -p /var/run/guacd.pid
root      1156     1  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/postfix/master
postfix   1176  1156  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 pickup -l -t fifo -u
postfix   1177  1156  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 qmgr -l -t fifo -u
tomcat    1224     1  0 15:05 ?        00:00:02 /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -Djava
root      1242     1  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 crond
wesley    1276     1  0 15:05 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/Xvnc :1 -desktop vnc.le
wesley    1286     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ck-xinit-session /usr/b
wesley    1290  1286  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 vncconfig -iconic
mark      1313     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:02 /usr/bin/Xvnc :2 -desktop vnc.le
wesley    1320     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-w
wesley    1321     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-
root      1327     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --n
wesley    1395  1286  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/gnome-session
wesley    1397  1395  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /etc/X11/xini
root      1411     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/devkit-power-daemon
wesley    1416     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
mark      1434     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ck-xinit-session /usr/b
mark      1435  1434  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 vncconfig -iconic
mark      1450     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-w
mark      1454     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-
sylvia    1472     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/Xvnc :3 -desktop vnc.le
mark      1477  1434  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/gnome-session
mark      1478  1477  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /etc/X11/xini
mark      1489     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
wesley    1491     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 gnome-keyring-daemon --start
wesley    1494     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gnome-settings-daem
mark      1500     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 gnome-keyring-daemon --start
mark      1503     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gnome-settings-daem
mark      1511     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd
wesley    1513     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd
mark      1530  1477  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 metacity
wesley    1531  1395  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 metacity
sylvia    1535     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ck-xinit-session /usr/b
sylvia    1536  1535  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 vncconfig -iconic
sylvia    1552     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-w
sylvia    1555     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-
sylvia    1569  1535  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/gnome-session
sylvia    1570  1569  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /etc/X11/xini
naomi     1583     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/Xvnc :4 -desktop vnc.le
sylvia    1585     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
sylvia    1594     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 gnome-keyring-daemon --start
sylvia    1597     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gnome-settings-daem
mark      1600  1477  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 gnome-panel
wesley    1601  1395  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 gnome-panel
sylvia    1604     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd
wesley    1612     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --lo
mark      1613     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --lo
rtkit     1615     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/rtkit-daemon
sylvia    1616  1569  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 metacity
root      1621     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/polkit-1/polkitd
sylvia    1622  1569  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 gnome-panel
sylvia    1625     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --lo
wesley    1626  1612  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/pulse/gconf-helper
mark      1627  1613  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/pulse/gconf-helper
sylvia    1628  1625  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/pulse/gconf-helper
mark      1631  1477  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 nautilus
mark      1633     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/bonobo-activation-s
wesley    1634  1395  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 nautilus
wesley    1636     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/bonobo-activation-s
sylvia    1640  1569  0 15:06 ?        00:00:01 nautilus
sylvia    1642     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/bonobo-activation-s
mark      1655     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/wnck-applet --oaf-a
sylvia    1658     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/wnck-applet --oaf-a
sylvia    1661     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/trashapplet --oaf-a
wesley    1662     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/wnck-applet --oaf-a
sylvia    1666     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfs-gdu-volume-mon
wesley    1667     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfs-gdu-volume-mon
wesley    1668     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/trashapplet --oaf-a
mark      1669     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/trashapplet --oaf-a
mark      1671     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfs-gdu-volume-mon
root      1673     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/udisks-daemon
mark      1684     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-trash --spawn
wesley    1686     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-trash --spawn
sylvia    1688     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-trash --spawn
root      1689  1673  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 udisks-daemon: not polling any d
sylvia    1693  1569  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 gpk-update-icon
mark      1694  1477  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 gpk-update-icon
wesley    1695  1395  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 gpk-update-icon
mark      1705  1477  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/polkit-gnome-authen
sylvia    1706  1569  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/polkit-gnome-authen
wesley    1707  1395  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/polkit-gnome-authen
wesley    1714  1395  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 xdg-user-dirs-gtk-update
wesley    1717  1395  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 gnome-power-manager
sylvia    1720  1569  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 xdg-user-dirs-gtk-update
sylvia    1721  1569  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 gnome-power-manager
mark      1725  1477  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 gnome-power-manager
wesley    1734  1395  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 gnome-volume-control-applet
sylvia    1735  1569  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 gnome-volume-control-applet
mark      1737  1477  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 gnome-volume-control-applet
sylvia    1768     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 gnome-screensaver
wesley    1769     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 gnome-screensaver
naomi     1773     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ck-xinit-session /usr/b
naomi     1775  1773  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 vncconfig -iconic
naomi     1787     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-w
naomi     1792     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-
mark      1804     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 gnome-screensaver
naomi     1807  1773  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/gnome-session
naomi     1808  1807  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /etc/X11/xini
root      1814     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/atd
root      1819   717  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /etc/rc3.d/S99firstboo
naomi     1823     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
root      1827  1819  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/sbin/first
mark      1831     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gdm-user-switch-app
mark      1833     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/clock-applet --oaf-
mark      1835     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/notification-area-a
sylvia    1841     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gdm-user-switch-app
sylvia    1843     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/notification-area-a
sylvia    1846     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/clock-applet --oaf-
wesley    1850     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gdm-user-switch-app
wesley    1852     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/clock-applet --oaf-
wesley    1854     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/notification-area-a
naomi     1864     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 gnome-keyring-daemon --start
naomi     1867     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gnome-settings-daem
naomi     1873     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd
naomi     1879  1807  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 metacity
naomi     1881  1807  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 gnome-panel
naomi     1896     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --lo
naomi     1901  1807  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 nautilus
naomi     1904     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/bonobo-activation-s
naomi     1907  1807  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 gpk-update-icon
naomi     1910  1807  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/polkit-gnome-authen
naomi     1917     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/wnck-applet --oaf-a
naomi     1920     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/trashapplet --oaf-a
naomi     1921  1807  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 xdg-user-dirs-gtk-update
naomi     1922  1807  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 gnome-power-manager
naomi     1927  1807  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 gnome-volume-control-applet
naomi     1933     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfs-gdu-volume-mon
naomi     1934  1896  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/pulse/gconf-helper
naomi     1945     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-trash --spawn
naomi     1952     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 gnome-screensaver
naomi     1958     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/clock-applet --oaf-
naomi     1959     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gdm-user-switch-app
naomi     1961     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/notification-area-a
mark      1972     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-metadata
wesley    1983     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-metadata
sylvia    1993     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-metadata
root      2003  1827  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 setup
root      2040  1706  0 15:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/polkit-1/polkit-age
root      2041  1910  0 15:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/polkit-1/polkit-age
root      2044  1705  0 15:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/polkit-1/polkit-age
root      2062  1058  0 15:37 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@pts/0
root      2068  2062  0 15:37 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
root      2086  2068  0 15:39 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -eaf
```

Comment: What do the details show when you unroll them at the bottom? I'd also take a look at the output of `ps -eaf` to see what processes are related to this dialog being presented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would appear to be the process, `gpk-update-icon` that's responsible for this authentication window being popped open.

You could try this solution:

> Sorry for the misunderstanding. The app is for the Gnome Package kit, many people have reported that they fixed it by removing gnome and using another window manager, and other have said that you can go to System->Preferences->Personal->Sessions and Untick "PackageKit Update Applet" to stop the applet.

*Source: http://www.linux.com/community/forums/desktop/gpk-update-icon*

I would merely try unticking the "PackageKit Update Applet" as a workaround.